# IE 9 focus wraps around contents correct(!) while Firefox 12.0 doesn't seem to

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

When opening up http://mitchwillfixit.com/mbc/media.php and then tabbing to the clickable pictures on that page, I get different result in IE 9 and Firefox 12.0.  IE 9 "wraps around" the images correctly whereas Firefox 12.0 is wrapping in an odd manner.  If you go to the media.php page and tab through the content symbols you'll see what I mean.

The links are opening fine and all, but it bothers me how Firefox wraps around the focussed images.

Any way to get Firefox to wrap around those images like IE 9 does?

Comment: Never, ever use IE as a reference as to how things should work. IE9 may be doing what you want but Firefox will do what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's happening because you have `text-indent: -9999px;` on each of the three `a` elements.

If this really matters to you, pick a different [image replacement technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/).